# UICollection View custom Cells Layout

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

Im trying to build a demo app (training on my skillz )

That demo app has a vertical Collection View screen that has Cells with Image Views 
and a View with Labels

The layout as it is - each cell 150 width and 415 height 2 cells per row going vertically

I want to make each cell to be at different cell height regarding on the image inside the imageView, and then I want to make sure that each cell sticks up to the cell above it

When I tried to do it I managed to change the cell size proportionally, but I couldnt change the cell Y position

Anyway here's my entire code hope you guys understood what I mean, Thanks alot in advance

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var imagesArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Forest"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Tree") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "hinna"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "beach1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "work"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ya"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bird"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "rose"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Tree"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Labra") ]

    var labelsArray = ["bahwaijf", "abwohd", "owauhduo", "awodh"]

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self

       }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagesArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionVCe

         cell.cellImg.image = imagesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.descLabel.text = descArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.itemLabel.text = labelsArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the cells insets? You can do it on the interface builder or programmatically.

Interface Builder:

[image]

Programmatically:

```
let collectionViewLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout

collectionViewLayout?.sectionInset = ... // some UIEdgeInset

collectionViewLayout?.invalidateLayout()
```

Comment: I did try that, my problem is the result im getting are 2 cells at each row but the next row doesnt stack up to the 1st row if the cell size is smaller 

I mean lets say I have 4 squares, 
2 on each line, 
the first line has a Left square which is 380 in height and the right one is 415 , 
the second row starts and 415 on the left side eventho the space has between cells is bigger because the first cell is 380 and not 415, it should start at 380 on the 2nd row but it doesnt